# Player Controller's Fast /Run function doesnt work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 3d first person, horror game in unity with c sharp and i have made a script to control the movements of the player along with a 'Character Controller' Component.
W - forwards
A - left
S - backwards
D - right

left control - when pressed, crawls the player if standing, and vice versa (stands the player if crawling).

left shift - when pressed while moving forward(W), enables to move fast if timer is <=0, disables running when timer >= Countdown, or releases W key (not moving forward) or when pressed left shift while running.
[note that player can be speed while standing or crawling]

space - jump

here is the script...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character_Movement_V2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;

    //test
    public float showSpeed;

    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float gravityMultiplier = 3f;
    public float verticalVelocity;

    public float movspeed = 1f;

    public float isFastSpeed = 1f;
    public float CrawlSpeed = 1f;

    public bool isCrawling;
    public bool isFast;

    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    public float jumpCooldown = 4f;
    public float jumpTimer;

    public float isFastTimer;
    public float isFastCooldown = 6f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        jumpTimer = jumpCooldown;
        isFastTimer = isFastCooldown;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MovePlayer();
        Fast();
        Crawl();
        JumpandGravity();
    }

    public void MovePlayer()
    {
        //Move Player

        //check
        Vector3 move = (movspeed * isFastSpeed * CrawlSpeed * (transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) + transform.up * verticalVelocity);
        characterController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);

        //test
        showSpeed = Mathf.Sqrt((move.x) * (move.x) + (move.z) * (move.z));
    }

    public void Fast()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (isFastTimer <= 0f && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                isFast = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isFast = false;
        }
       
        if ((isFast && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) || (isFastTimer >= isFastCooldown))
        {
            isFast = false;
        }

        if (isFast)
        {
            isFastSpeed = 3f;
        }
        else
        {
            isFastSpeed = 1f;
        }

        //isFast Timer
        if(isFast && isFastTimer < isFastCooldown)
        {
            isFastTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if(!isFast && 0f < isFastTimer)
        {
            isFastTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    public void Crawl()
    {
        if(!isCrawling && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            isCrawling = true;
        }
        else if(isCrawling && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            isCrawling = false;
        }

        if(isCrawling)
        {
            CrawlSpeed = 0.25f;
        }
        else
        {
            CrawlSpeed = 1f;
        }
    }

    public void JumpandGravity()
    {
       
        //Jump
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && jumpTimer <= 0f)
            {
                verticalVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity * gravityMultiplier);
                jumpTimer = jumpCooldown;
            }
            else
            {
                verticalVelocity = -1f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Gravity
            verticalVelocity += gravity * gravityMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        //Jump Cooldown
        if (jumpTimer > 0f)
        {
            jumpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (jumpTimer < 0f)
        {
            jumpTimer = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

However, all of these functions work except the Fast() function.

The player doesnt run when pressed the leftShift.

Cant seem to figure out the problem here.
Any answer could be a help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: your code is so confused.  So  if pressing W, and a timer is <=0 and left sjhift set fast, otherwise flase, irrelevant of what you just decided (note you will potentially have set isfast true), if isfast is true, from the last statement and pressing left shift - which you already just checked....  OR timer is greater than isfastcooldown set it to false, so. you checked it was W and left, you said yes, and immediately set it to no again..   Debug my friend

Comment: @BugFinder doesn't the fast set to NO when the W key is NOT PRESSED cuz the else statement goes with it? So it should still work ig. It doesn't switch immediately.

Comment: I have to agree with @BugFinder. This code is a logical nightmare. Write your rules for fast and slow down. And make them modify your player move speed in one logical place. You can debug what you have with a debugger and step through each line checking how the values are modified, but what you really need is for the code to read more straightforwardly. The fact it's not easy to tell what's going on due to the flipping back and forth between true and false with many statements is the main problem.

Comment: @A.A.Knightmare well yes when W is not pressed its set to false - however, the first half of the if sets it true and because what made that true is still true, it will then set it to false.. it would be a lot clearer if you rethink that whole bit out and simplify

Comment: for instance you do `MovePlayer` **before** you actually check for `Fast` .. shouldn't this rather be in opposite order? Further you shouldn't be mixing the `GetKey<KeyCode.W>` with `GetAxis("Horizontal")` it is a bit error prone as your axis settings might be different (for instance also reacting to arrow keys) .. you could rather store the input for both axes in a `Vector2` and check for `input.y > 0`

Comment: also logic wise I think crawling and fast should probably be exclusive .. or can you also crawl fast? ^^

Comment: @derHugo yes we can crawl fast too.

Comment: @derHugo how about checking whether GetAxis("Horizontal")>0 then?

Comment: as said you anyway use `GetAxis` so store the result `private Vector2 moveInput;` and `moveInput = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), 1f);` and then you can check `if(moveInput.y > 0)`